# Godot 4 Get data from an <EncodedObjectAsID#-9223371956710013181>

Tags: godot, gdscript

When I save my scene data to a file using this GDScript code

When obtaining the data, it is obtained as <EncodedObjectAsID#-9223371956710013181> , instead of a scene

```
my_data = {
    'levels': [Level.new('1')]
}   

func save_data():
    var file = FileAccess.open(save_file, FileAccess.WRITE)
    if file:
        file.store_var(my_data)
        file.close()
```

**How can I get the data from the scene I saved, and how can I prevent it from being saved that way?**

Answer (score 0):

Here `store_var` is storing a reference. If you want it to store the object instance, you need to specify the second parameter `full_objects` to `true`:

```
file.store_var(my_data, true)
```

Be aware that this might include code. That is, custom GDScript classes are attached `GDScript` objects (on the `script` property). Furthermore, that means:

- This mechanism might load code (potential code injection, or potential modding hook, depending what you do with it).
- And loading script with named classes will result in conflict with the already loaded counterparts.